# JavaFX Alert - Graphic Not Taking Total Width

Tags: image, javafx, alert

I'm trying to get Alert to accept an image and set that image to the total width of the Alert/vice versa (have Alert shrink to splash width/height)

Here's my attempted code.

```
Alert test = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
    Image image = new Image("splash.jpg");
    ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
    test.setGraphic(view);
    test.setWidth(image.getWidth());
    test.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Image img = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("splash.jpg").toExternalForm());
BackgroundFill fill = new BackgroundFill(new ImagePattern(img), null, null);

Alert test = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
test.getDialogPane().setBackground(new Background(fill));
test.setResizable(true);
test.show();
```